# Show first div on page load and hide others and then show the rest on click of the menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am working on a menu where on click of the navigation items, the div will be shown, but by default, the first div should be shown and rest hidden. They should be seen only on click of other navigation items.

Below is my code that I have tried so far.

**The HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
                    <li class="page_item current_page_item justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div1">a</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div2">b</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div3">c</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div4">d</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div5">e</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div6">f</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div7">g</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div8">h</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2 justClick"><a href="#" data-id="div9">i</a></li>
                </ul>

<div class="content">

</div>

<div class="content1">
cccc1
</div>

<div class="content2">
cccc2
</div>

<div class="content3">
cccc3
</div>

<div class="content4">
cccc4
</div>

<div class="content5">
cccc5
</div>

<div class="content6">
cccc6
</div>

<div class="content7">
cccc7
</div>

<div class="content8">
cccc8
</div>

<div class="content9">
cccc9
</div>
```

**The Script:**

```
$('.justClick').bind('click', function() {      
    $('div.content').html($('div.content' + ($(this).index()+1)).html());
});
```

**The CSS:**

```
.content {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**The JSFiddle link:**

http://jsfiddle.net/6uzU6/

I am getting to achieve the onclick functionality on the click of navigation items on click of them, but all the div's are visible.

What I want, is that all the div's except first div (with the class .content) should be hidden and when you click on the navigation items, it should show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div').not(".content,.content1").hide();
$('.justClick').bind('click', function() {      
    $('div').not(".content").hide();
    $('div.content').html($('div.content' + ($(this).index()+1)).html());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6uzU6/2/)**

Comment: Works fine except that `div.content1` should be visible on page load.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there is something missing in your code because there is no relation between the links and div you want to show. you will require more attributes on to maintain a relations between them.

A better approach would be apply a common class to all div like 'content-block' and class equal to  use following code.

```
$(".content-block:not(:first)").hide();
```

and show respective div on click on link

```
$("#menu li").click(function(e){    
 $(".content-block").eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

you can use other parameters as well to relate them instead of index.

Comment: Thanks @Swati . I am not that sound in jQuery, so arranged bits and pieces to make that work. Coming to your answer, `.content-block:not(:first)` will work on cross browser ?? +1 for putting time to answer my question :)

Comment: if it not work use `$(".content-block").hide()` and the show first with `$(".content-block:eq(0)").show()`

Comment: I tried your solution, but does not work for me. Demo link below. http://jsfiddle.net/6uzU6/4/ - @Swati

Comment: I dont see any fiddle updated by you. I assume you have forgot to link it. - @Swati

Answer (score 0):

```
Give attribute to div runat="server" and Id="dv1"
using property display block and none u can show or hide it
```